# Return does not output any value, however, print does. Python interpreter problem?

Tags: python, pythoninterpreter

```
def x1():
    y = input("Input pet here: ")
    if y == "pet":
        return True
    else:
        return False
x1()

def x2():
    y = input("Input pet here: ")
    if y == "pet":
        print(y)
    else:
        print("not a pet")
x2()
```

Output:
C:\Users\jiraf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe "C:/Users/jiraf/OneDrive/Documents/Grzegorz/Programowanie/Python/kurs/1.02/Wykład 1.8 Funkcje (definiowanie, argumenty).py"

Input pet here: shit
Input pet here: shit
not a pet

Process finished with exit code 0
[image]

I have tried with many easy functions that simply should return something

I have no idea why is that.

Comment: What do you expect for first function?

Comment: try to run `x1()` as `print(x1())`.

Comment: Functions don't print anything on return - why do you expect them to?

Comment: In the updated post. It should output True. I'll post more pictures with different functions in a minute.

Comment: Abhishek now it works but it should work without printing shouldn't it?

Comment: function x1 just return the value for printing the value you have to use the print function

Comment: Oh I get it, my bad then. Hahaha thanks so much for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` does not print to output, it just returns function result. You may have seen this printing when using `python shell` as it does print result for some needed reasons.

For your 1st function to print you must print the called function like this

```
print(x1())
```

Comment: what do you mean by python shell?

Comment: As a tip. Python fucntions always return (except maybe some built-in functions). Either you declare return statement explicitly, or python function returns `None` when it reaches the end of function. The function is always a thing that returns. Function is also callable, so the print(x1()) actualy does next steps. Python sees nested calls, so it calls from inside. First it calls x1, which returns True or False, after the result is returned, print is called with that result, so you end up with either print(True) or print(False)

Comment: @Jirafey python shell is a tool that comes with python. When you want to run your commands line by line or some other reasons you can just type `python` or `py` or `python3` in console or terminal and by doing that you will start python shell

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not a interpreter issue.  I can't quite tell what editor you are running, but I'm pretty certain that editors such as Jupyter only print the last executed line in a chunk. That is very likely what is going on here. You should either run `print(x1())` or something like

```py
x = x1()
y= x2()
print(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: it's Pycharm, it's just my bad I thought it would just print value automatically.

Comment: Totally understandable. Its a strange nuance to get tripped up on if you don't expect it. More importantly, though, is the difference between printing a value to the console and returning a value. Both method calls return a value, but only one is printed to console.